# How to Integrate Apple Pay with Stripe in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, stripe-payments, applepay

i'm following that blog entrance, https://agileapp.co/Stripe-and-ApplePay-with-Xamarin-Forms/, that tells us how to integrate Stripe with Apple Pay using Xamarin Forms.

I follow all code, and the only thing I changed is in PaymentButtonRenderer, CountryCode and CurrencyCode properties of PKPaymentRequest, set for use in Spain (ES and EUR), and of course, MerchantIdentifier as I set in apple developer portal.

All things I have to do in Stripe are already done.

As you can see in the images below, payment is not finished, and I don't know why. I don't know where I have to set the pay using Stripe (var myCharge = new ChargeCreateOptions()....), maybe in PCL ViewModel, in PaymentWillAuthorize or PaymentDidAuthorize... but I have two breakpoints and PaymentDidAuthorize never breaks, only PaymentWillAuthorize , but I don't know how I have to code in these methods.

Another extrange thing, is that if I use MerchantCapabilities as PKMerchantCapability.ThreeDS, I have an error message that tells that "Apple Pay is not available in my App", but if I change it to PKMerchantCapability.Debit, then the payment not finish.

Could you tell me what is wrong??

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Payment not complete" is a symptom that your code never calls `completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus.Success);` after you completed the payment on your backend sever. You need to call that completion handler (the callback that's passed to DidAuthorizePayment) to tell the device that it can close the Apple Pay sheet. The usual flow is that in DidAuthorizePayment you make a call to your backend sever, attempt the payment using the token, and then when your app gets the response from your server it calls that function.  It doesn't look like the code you shared does that (it's commented out)

Comment: ok @karllekko, but as I said, PaymentDidAuthorize never fires, only PaymentWillAuthorize....

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure. Are there errors in your app logs? They would be in XCode, but I'm not sure how it works with Xamarin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine, I just only create apple merchant certificate again, and code does what it have to do.

Problem solved, thanks @karllekko